# What are the chemicals present in body of paddle worm which makes it show biolumniscence

Tags: species

Paddle worm is the light emitting species i want to know that
1. What are the chemicals which produce this light? 
2. For what purpose it needs this light?

Comment: The compound used for bioluminescence could very well be [Luciferin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luciferin), and the reason for the light is to assist in the spawning process, with the females releasing a bioluminescent "capsule" [of eggs] that the males can easily identify.

Comment: Thanks charles but Can you please elaborate